# Trouble getting new datanodes to add in a High Availability, Federated environment

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, high-availability

I am trying to setup/maintain 3 HDFS Clusters, all using High Availability.  They all work fine on there own, but I want to use HDFS Federation to help them talk to each other.

I am using Cloudera 420, and have used their guide to set it all up.  For each cluster, the core-site.xml files are different (fs.defaultFS), yet the hdfs-site.xml are all the same.  The hdfs-site.xml file lists all the nameservices (dfs.nameservices), which, of course, reference back to the corresponding core-site.xml.  Each cluster has a slaves file which lists the datanodes that should belong to it.

My trouble is in adding a new datanode.  I set it up with the configuration files (core, hdfs, slaves, etc.) for the cluster I want it to join.  However, when I start the datanode up, it appears to try to join to the first cluster listed in the dfs.nameservices property.  I would think it would look at the fs.defaultFS property first, but it does not appear to do that.  The wrong cluster seems to accept it as well, despite the new datanode not being in the slaves file.

Bottom line, my new datanode is trying to join the wrong cluster.  How does it know which one to join?

Thanks, in advance, for any ideas.

** UPDATE **

Maybe I just misunderstand the use case for doing this.  When I look through the Hadoop code, it appears a thread for each dfs.nameservices entry is started.  Each of these tries to assign its CID to a single DataNode object, but only if it is already null.  It appears to do this without regard to order, which means first one wins.  Only if I get "lucky" will it chose the correct one.  If I am not "lucky", which I am usually not, it gets another one... and connects there first.  Strange.